# SNR for good MRI imaging

Tags: mri

Resolution of MRI can be improved if FOV is reduced keeping other factors constant, but this reduces voxel volume, which in turn reduces SNR. How much SNR is enough for good imaging?

Comment: WTF are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

[Old question, but...]

There is an old adage in MRI:  **High signal to noise, high resolution, short scan time... choose 2.**

The question of "How much SNR is enough?" can't be answered without talking about specifics, primarily, what is the scan going to be used for?

For example, a typical MS diagnostic scan doesn't really need to be too high a resolution or signal to noise as **typically** the lesions are large and hyperintense.  BUT with higher field scanners one is able to see smaller and smaller lesions.

If one is doing quantitative work off of an MRI scan, then it will depend on the type of quantification, algorithm etc.

So, in some ways the question is very broad and it depends, significantly, on a lot of other factors.

Doing some Google Scholar / Pubmed searches for SNR and MRI might help with specific areas you are interested in (e.g., https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C9&q=minimum+signal+to+noise+ratio+in+magnetic+resonance+imaging&btnG=)